# How would you parse in bash #extra_modules <string>

Tags: regex, bash, parsing

How would I parse

```
 #extra_modules some string
```

in kdump.conf file to get "some string" as actual output in bash script ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "#extra_modules" kdump.conf | cut -c 16-
```

grep finds the lines with the phrase "#extra_modules", and cut selects all the characters after the first space

Comment: How about regex ? Can we do it using regex ?

Comment: Do you need a regex?  If you are just looking for the lines starting with `"#extra_modules"`, then grepping for `#extra_modules` suffices.

Comment: `grep` without `-F` switch is always regex

Comment: @gwillie most grep implementations are clever enough to perform the fixed string algorithm when invoked without `-F`.

Comment: @Nirk that's nifty, didn't know that :)

Comment: Yes, that was dumb question by me